# How to give the user the ability to edit already selected data in the vue-select component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have vue-select component: https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/
and I want to give my users the ability to edit already selected data, I did not find such an opportunity in the documentation, maybe someone dealt with this component and will tell.

`<v-select :options="myOptions" taggable v-model="value"
</v-select>`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6dV2.png)

Comment: Why would someone want to edit the selected data ? Even if you type in something you can only select the value from the defined list.

Comment: because there are not only values ​​from the list, but also values ​​that the user can enter

Comment: Alright I will post the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintainer answered that now there is no such possibility.

https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select/issues/806

Answer (score 0):

That feature is called "tagging", Vue Select supports it through the taggable prop:

```
<v-select taggable></v-select>
```

It's in the documentation as well, if you want to take a look and know more: [Vue Select - Tagging](https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/docs/Basics/Values.html#tagging).

Comment: I use taggable. see above ^^